# Taking and saving pictures in Firemonkey

Tags: image, delphi, camera, save, firemonkey

I use Firemonkey XE5 to take picture and save to device. I use standard action `TakePhotoFromCameraAction` and `on DidFinishTaking get TBitmap`. That's OK, but when I try to store this picture using

```
ImageContainer.Bitmap.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'myfile.bmp');
```

Nothing happens. Image is not stored, but application seems to be running - I can take another picture.

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem before.
After tracing ***SaveToFile*** function in **FMX.Graphix.TBitmap.SaveToFile**, then to **FMX.Graphix.TBitmapCodecManager.SaveToFile** function, I found that this function return **False** because:

```
if SameText(ExtractFileExt(AFileName), Descriptor.Extension, loUserLocale) and Descriptor.CanSave then
```

the **if** condition return False because the Descriptor.Extension is **'.jpg'** not **'.bmp'**.

So the solution is to use **'.jpg'** extension for the file or to use SaveParams (Default = nil) parameter in SaveToFile function to match the bmp type.

Comment: Hi Oussama... Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I understood / your solution works... I changed extension to jpg, but it didn't help. 

Now I have
ImageContainer.Bitmap.SaveToFile(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'myfile.jpg');

and it's still not ok.

What's your code? Could you share it please to me?

Comment: My Code is:
ImageFile := System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetSharedDownloadsPath, 'MyImage.jpg');
ImageControl.Bitmap.SaveToFile(ImageFile);
It works fine for me.
If it is not working for you, I suggest you to trace it over into SaveToFile Function and find out what is the problem.

Comment: I had the same issue.  Traced it into TBitmapCodecManager.FindWritableCodecClass and this function only supports saving png;jpg;jpeg. Not bmp, so when I changed my fileextention to .jpg instead it saved.  Can you flippen believe it.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar Problems, however, it was not a Problem of saving. My Problem was actually that the device was connected to my Computer through usb. I opend the device in the file Explorer and I would not be able to see the Pictures I just saved. I then disconnected the device and connected it again, opening a new file Explorer and there they where....